# Buildout - Allow hosts for package download

Tags: plone, easy-install, buildout, zodb

I have a Plone 5.0.5 deployment and the need the package zc.zrs for ZODB replication. After adding the information to the buildout.cfg, I've added the URL https://pypi.org/simple on the index parameter:

```
[buildout]
extends = 
    base.cfg
    versions.cfg
index = https://pypi.org/simple
```

Then I run the buildout and get the following error:

```
# sudo -u plone_buildout bin/buildout

Installing 'plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs]'.
We have the distribution that satisfies 'plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs]==1.2.9'.
Getting required 'zc.zrs'
We have no distributions for zc.zrs that satisfies 'zc.zrs'.
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple: hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org' -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/zc.zrs/: hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org' -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.zrs' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org' -- Some packages may not be found!
Getting distribution for 'zc.zrs'.
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.zrs' (maybe misspelled?)
Could't load zc.buildout entry point default
from plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs]:
Couldn't find a distribution for 'zc.zrs'..
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section zeoserver.
  Initializing section zeoserver.
  Installing recipe plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs].
  Getting distribution for 'zc.zrs'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'zc.zrs'.
```

After doing some research find out that the buildout uses easy_install, and tryed to add some parameters described from [this documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html#restricting-downloads-with-allow-hosts), but I'm getting the same errors like doesn't changed nothing.

How can I allow the download from [PyPI](https://pypi.org) from Plone buildout?

Comment: You should also thing about doing an update of your Plone to a supported Version: 5.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plone buildout should be able to download from pypi by default.
Check if you can download with wget into your download folder:

wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/b2/5a516f4883fc766ea37a9d979a5cacddc1b29df17140c14da26676a3c4b5/zc.zrs-3.1.0.tar.gz

You should have a downloads folder in your buildout-cache folder, if you are using the default installer.
I do that sometimes when the server has some strange network configurations and can't download some packages directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done as you said and it worked, for little maintenance it will suffice. What I have observed is that that error might be related to the SSL verification of the urllib2, the SSL certificate of the domain *.pythonhosted.org doesn't match the "domain of download", and it throw that error. I've tryied to use other PiPY mirror at [this address](https://mirrors.sustech.edu.cn/pypi/simple) and the buildout worked successfully... I think a issue shoud be opened at the source.

Comment: Changed the index link by that ```index = https://mirrors.sustech.edu.cn/pypi/simple```